# Not able to convert scientific notation to number in R

Tags: r

Can anyone help me converting exp to numeric in R

```
> asd <-data.frame(a = c(1234254535343,423), b= c("a","f"))
> asd$a <- scientific(asd$a, digits = 3)
> asd
         a b
1 1.23e+12 a
2 4.23e+02 f

> asd$a <- format(asd$a, scientific = FALSE)
> asd
         a b
1 1.23e+12 a
2 4.23e+02 f
```

Expected output

```
> asd
         a      b
1 1234254535343 a
2 423           f
```

Comment: I tried with format function, but failing

Comment: Use `options(scipen = 999)`.

Comment: Where Should i declare it. I put it in my server.R file but not working